# pandas checking for nan not working using .isin()

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have the following pandas Dataframe with a `NaN` in it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,float('nan')], columns=['A'])
df

    A
0   1
1   2
2   3
3 NaN
```

I also have the list `filter_list` using which I want to filter my Dataframe. But if i use `.isin()` function, it is not detecting the `NaN`. Instead of getting `True` I am getting `False` in the last row

```
filter_list = [1, float('nan')]

df['A'].isin(filter_list)
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Expected output:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

I know that I can use `.isnull()` to check for `NaNs`. But here I have other values to check as well. I am using pandas `0.16.0` version

Edit: The list `filter_list` comes from the user. So it might or might not have `NaN`. Thats why i am using `.isin()`

Comment: This won't work because `np` uses the fact that `NaN != NaN` which is why this fails, so you'd have to filter the `NaN` values first and then filter the other values

Comment: is there a way where i can create the `NaN` element in the `filter_list`, so that pandas understands it?

Comment: No I don't think so, for instance `df['A'] == float('nan')` still won't work, bottom line is you have to use `isnull` or `notnull` to test for `NaN` correctly

Comment: Sanitize your user inputs! Don't let them input NaN! Fillna with some appropreate NA value and do the same to the user inputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could replace `nan` with a unique non-NaN value that will not occur in your list, say `'NA'` or `''`. For example:

```
In [23]: import pandas as pd

In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, pd.np.nan], columns=['A'])

In [25]: filter_list = pd.Series([1, pd.np.nan])

In [26]: na_equiv = 'NA'

In [27]: df['A'].replace(pd.np.nan, na_equiv).isin(filter_list.replace(pd.np.nan, na_equiv))
Out[27]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 8):

The float NaN has the interesting property that [it is not equal to itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1565164/190597):

```
In [194]: float('nan') == float('nan')
Out[194]: False
```

`isin` checks for equality. So you can't use `isin` to check if a value *equals* NaN.
To check for NaNs it is best to use `np.isnull`.

---

```
In [200]: df['A'].isin([1]) | df['A'].isnull()
Out[200]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Comment: The problem is the list `filter_list` comes from the user. So it might or might not have `NaN`

Comment: Either change the user interface so that `filter_nan` is an additional parameter and NaN is not included in `filter_list`, or else check `pd.isnull(filter_list).any()` and handle the cases accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the simplest way is to use `numpy.nan`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, np.nan], columns=['A'])
filter_list = [1, np.nan]
df['A'].isin(filter_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really what to use `isin()` to match NaN. You can create a class that has the same hash as nan and return True when compare to nan:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class NAN(object):
    def __eq__(self, v):
        return np.isnan(v)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(np.nan)

nan = NAN()

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,float('nan')], columns=['A'])
df.A.isin([1, nan])
```

Comment: Much easier option is to write the following:

import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,np.nan], columns=['A'])