# pandas DataFrame style, highlight nan's

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-styles

Say with this DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['A','B'], 'date' : pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-01','2000-01-02']), 'value' : [np.nan, 1]})

        date name  value
0 2000-01-01    A    NaN
1 2000-01-02    B    1.0
```

How can I check which element is `nan` inside `df.applymap`? (ie, not using `df.isnull`)

The problem comes from where I want to use the pandas html styling. We have the built-in nan highlighting

```
df.style.highlight_null()
```

but it changes the background colour, instead I want "nan" to be displayed in red.

So I need to do it myself with `applymap`

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'color: red' if isnan(x) else '')
```

But how can I check if a value is nan, when it can also be datetime/string? `np.isnan` will fail on strings. `np.isreal(x) and np.isnan(x)` also fails on datetime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [pd.isnull()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html), which deals with a wider range of types for missing values check:

```
import pandas as pd
df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'color: red' if pd.isnull(x) else '')
```

[image]

Comment: anyway to display nan as '-'?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that floating point  ̀NaN` values [are not equal to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31833758/2641825):

```
df.style.applymap(lambda x: '' if x==x else 'color: red')
```